# WP7 LongListSelector - find control inside DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a collection bound to a longlistselector. When a button in the applicationbar is clicked, I want to show a column that was previously hidden inside the longlistselector. How can I get access to the grid inside my datatemplate so I can toggle the column's visibility?

I tried the FindName method but it keeps returning null for the control I want. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than finding the  inside the template, how about binding the Visibility property of the 's contents to a property in your view model. Then all you need to do is change the view models property and the 's contents will show or hide.